# Why does dot star give two matches in replacing a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
("ppa").replace(/(.*)/g,'o') = "oo"
```

Don't understand why the result isn't just "o"

Comment: Note that this behavior does not occur without the `/g` global modifier. Additionally you will get this behavior for each new line in the text since `.` does not match newlines in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `o` == `.*` capturing `ppa`

Second `o` == `.*` capturing `empty string after ppa`.

Use `.+` for single `o`

Comment: so you mean to say 'ppa" is ( ppa + '') ? Not sur where the empty string is coming from

Comment: @airnet regex tries to match en empty string after `ppa`.Now `.*` is able to match it so it gets replaced as well.Because it is in `g` mode so it will not stop at first instance

Comment: @airnet more info here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/291273/why-regex-when-using-global-search-and-0-quantifier-match-the-end-of-the-st